# Do automatic objects in Python automatically get destroyed after exiting the scope?

Tags: python

I'm relatively new to Python and mostly only have coded with C++ before so I was wondering if I had a piece of code like this:

```
    for item in items:
       tree = Tree()
       trees.append(tree)
```

`trees` is a global variable. Would the destructor for tree get called automatically after we exit the for loop? In other words, outside of the loop could I still access `tree` through `trees`?

Comment: Python won't garbage-collect anything that is still accessible.  Everything you put into `trees` will hang around *at least* until `trees` goes out of scope.

Comment: Python allows you to create a destructor, but it is rarely used. Mainly because there's not much to destruct if you don't have to take care of the memory and there are also situations where the execution of the destructor is not guaranteed.